# Issue accessing my loopback API on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, heroku, loopback

I have created a fullstack app - Loopback is being used as the backend API and React as frontend app.
I was expecting to host my app on Heroku. I can successfully start the app (hosted on port 3000) and the client React is correctly displayed. However, when I try to send request to the API using this url `http://localhost:3000/api/`, I receive this error message :

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
```

Any ideas?

Thanks-

Comment: My guess is that we can't force the port for the Loopback API and 3000 is rejected by Heroku. Heroku seems to generate a port number automatically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because Heroku generate random port number, it's necessary to create 2 app: front end client and back end API.

Answer (score 0):

Your app won't be running on port 3000 when it's deployed to Heroku - you need to use the random port that it's assigned.  Also, your React front end should then use .herokuapp.com instead of localhost:3000. The React code is running on the client computer so it needs to make the request over the internet.

Comment: Thanks - Yes, that was my conclusion. Because of this random port number, I can't create a combined front/back end app on Heroku. I have now created 2 Heroku app, one for the client and one for the API - that works well.